# AsTask doesn't exist to implement a cancellation timeout for Async Read

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, cancellationtokensource

I am eager to add a time-out feature to my `stream.ReadAsync()` and read Microsoft help in this article [Async Cancellation: Bridging between the .NET Framework and the Windows Runtime (C# and Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj631575.aspx). This article suggests to use `AsTask()` to make this happen. However my C# doesn't seem to recognize `AsTask()` at all.

I am using **Visual Studio 2013** with **Windows 7** along with `using System.Threading;` and this is the piece of code I have:

```
private async Task<int> ReadAsync(BluetoothClient Client)
{
    const int timeoutMs = 10000;
    var cancelationToken = new CancellationTokenSource(timeoutMs);


    var stream = Client.GetStream();
    byte[] buffer = { 0 };
    int offset = 0;
    int count = 1;
    StatusManager("~Async Read Started...");

    //This line works perfectly fine.
    var rx = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, offset, count);
    //This line gets underlined with error for AsTask()
    var rx = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, offset, count).AsTask(cancelationToken);
    //rx.AsTask().Start();
    StatusManager("Recieved byte " + rx.ToString());
    StatusManager("~Async Read Finished.");
}
```

What am I missing here folks. I am puzzled :)

UPDATE: These are the list of .NET packages installed and I would say Visual Studio 2013 uses 4.5

[image]

Comment: what is your .NET framework version ?

Comment: My project was set to use 4.5

Comment: `AsTask` is specific to Windows Runtime. Are you developing a Windows Store app?

Comment: Not at all. This is the Windows Desktop software. Is Widows Runtime bound to develop Windows Store Apps only?!

Comment: @Mehrad, yes, it's for Windows Store apps only. You don't need `AsTask` for desktop .NET apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Noseratio commented, the `AsTask` in the linked article is for WinRT asynchronous operations, not BCL types.

In your case, you can just pass the cancellation token directly to the method:

```
var cancelationToken = new CancellationTokenSource(timeoutMs).Token;
...
var rx = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, offset, count, cancellationToken);
```

Comment: Wow, right under my nose. to be frank, I never knew Windows Runtime means = Windows Store App development. This fixed it all. Thank you all.