# BackgroundDownloader for Win 8.1 not working

Tags: c#, download, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I have a URL for a file something like "my.domain.com/myfile.doc" and if I open this in browser, a popup opens to enter username and password, after that I can view or download file.

Now I have to do this download in my Win 8.1 app. I used code below:

```
BackgroundDownloader backgroundDownloader = new BackgroundDownloader();
var credentials = GetNetworkCredential();
backgroundDownloader.ServerCredential = new Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordCredential("Lighthouse", credentials.UserName, credentials.Password);
CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

DownloadOperation downloadOperation = backgroundDownloader.CreateDownload(new Uri(System.Net.WebUtility.UrlDecode(searchDoc.Path)), fileToSave);
downloadOperation.StartAsync();
```

But nothing happens, no error and no data.

Comment: Have you tried to include your code in the try-catch block ? Without that exception can be thrown but lost. I have such an experience.

Comment: Thanks, already included.

Comment: I have done like this: try { await downloadOperation.StartAsync().AsTask();} catch (exception ex) { /* put breakpoint here */}

Comment: There is nothing like .AsTask(). Don't know why its not there because over net everybody used this as you mentioned.

Comment: Do you Windows store app writes ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22775015/astask-doesnt-exist-to-implement-a-cancellation-timeout-for-async-read

Comment: Also you can use AsTask() implementation from this topic http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/04/24/diving-deep-with-winrt-and-await.aspx

Comment: I think we are diverting from the topic.